# Root domain redirect, otherwise A record redirect

Tags: domain-name-system, .htaccess, cname-record, a-record

I would like to redirect every incoming request via `A record` to another server (url-shortening service) unless the root is requested.... Is this possible?  If so, how?  If not, why not?

A simple example of what I'm talking about:

- User requests short server website root: http://exmpl.com/

  - User is then redirected to much longer desired site: http://www.TheMostAwesomeExampleWebsite.com
- User requests specific short url: http://exmpl.com/randomPath

  - User is then redirected to desired server (where parsing is performed -> URL shortening/expanding service) via `A record` in DNS settings: 98.87.76.65

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; DNS cannot do HTTP redirects.

A DNS name is always resolved before HTTP communication even starts, and has no visibility into what URL is being requested.

However, I don't see why an HTTP redirect wouldn't work just fine for this case.

Can you clarify why you want DNS to be involved in the redirect?

Comment: I honestly don't know that it's a necessity to have DNS involved.  The service I'm using says to specify the A record, but if you think the HTTP redirect will suffice then I will try it.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this worked perfectly.  Thanks @Shane